# Why does Dijktra's algorithm require updating costs of already explored nodes?

Tags: dijkstra, path-finding

I'm implementing Dijktra's algorithm. To do this, I'm using one class, a vertex, which defines a point on the graph along with its edges and weights. As a sort of wrapper around this I have what I call a "node". This is nothing more than information about the vertex *and* what node was used to reach that vertex.

I also keep a list of all explored nodes. If a node is explored, we don't bother looking at it again. In all implementations I've seen, already explored vertices get added back to the frontier with a new total cost, if its found to be lower than what the current cost is. The argument is that if we find a new path to a node that is shorter than the one we took there originally, we must update the cost to reflect this and consider it again.

But how can this happen? When do we find ourselves in a scenario where a new path to the node is shorter than the one we've already found, considering we're expanding nodes with the shortest paths first?

Can someone show me an example where this updating and re-expanding is necessary to obtain the shortest path?

Comment: You're right, and re-expansion is never necessary for the reason you give. However, implementations of Dijkstra *don't* do that, so I find this question mysterious. A nodes parent and cost can only be changed like that while it is in the frontier, not after being expanded.

Comment: Ah, so by keeping track of which the parent node is I am implicitly updating the cost, I assume? See my comment to ryankuck's answer to see what I mean.

The implementation I saw did in fact re-expand already explored nodes, perhaps it was a bad implementation.

Comment: Generally the cost is explicitly kept as well to avoid recomputing it but yes. IDK what implementation you're looking at but for example the pseudocode [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm#Practical_optimizations_and_infinite_graphs) would not re-expand a node that has already been expanded

Comment: That pseudocode from wikipedia has the variant that *changes* the weight of a node in frontier, there is another variant that simply adds a new node to the frontier (which may be simpler to implement). That may misinterpreted as a re-expansion, though I'm not saying you're doing that, but anyway it isn't a re-expansion since the node in question has not been expanded yet. In this variant, the front can contain "dead nodes" that have a suboptimal parent, if they are popped off the front they should be discarded to avoid useless re-expansion.

Comment: Instead of *describing* your algorithm, please provide pseudo code and point out with it what you mean with re-expanding.

Answer (score 0):

[The Wikipedia entry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) for this show it in this gif.

[image]

I paused it exactly where what you described is happening. To get from node 1 to node 6 costs 14 directly, but from 1 to 3 to 6 only costs 9 + 2.

Since a neighbor may have a lower cost to reach than the first explored option, the lowest cost via any neighbor must be explored.

Comment: But I would consider these two entirely different nodes, since a node keeps information where it comes from. So our frontier would contain 6_1 with a cost of 14, and 6_3 with a cost of 11. Thus 6_3 would get expanded *before* 6_1. Then we mark 6_3 as explored. What I'm asking is, does this guarantee shortest path? To me it seems like it, since we are always expanding the shortest path first.

Comment: I believe you are thinking of a specific implementation of this, but in general a node is just a node and they are numbered 1-6 above with edges connecting some of them

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)